# Publish specific project from git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, azure

I've just deployed my repository from a git repository into Azure.

The repository is a Visual Studio 2012 solution with multiple web application projects but I only want a specific web application project to be the one that is used by Azure as the published web site.

Does anyone know how I can configure which project in the git repository is used by Azure as the published web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the answer:

I created a file called .deployment in the root of the git repository that contains a config clause that points to the relevant csproj file:

```
[config]
project = pathtomyproject/myproject.csproj
```